# Display [object HTMLDivElement] of google tag manager

Tags: css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to setup event tracking of my website using GTM.
However, when trying to debug a tag which fires on a CSS selector, I cannot properly determine which value my clicks are tacking since I can only see:

```
[object HTMLDivElement]
```

in the preview mode, like this:

[image]

So clearly, the second condition is not met, but I'm not sure why since I can only see the name of the object.

Is there a way to display this? perhaps using another custom tag, or sending the value to the data layer?

Comment: can you show how you set up your second condition in GTM ?

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly the element that is target of the click event do is not the one with id #navbar-brand. It seems to be a `div` inside your `#navbar-brand` element. If it's the case I'd suggest you to extend your firing condition to include all descendants of a #navbar-brand with selector `#navbar-brand *`